# Correct ordering of xr-hyper, hyperref, and cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, xr

I want to use `\cref`, external documents, and hyperrefs.  Take the following file, label it `main1.tex` and compile it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}     
\begin{document}
    \section{MyTitle}\label{sec:mytitle}            
\begin{equation}
A = b\label{eq:ab}
\end{equation}
  \end{document}
```

Now, take another file which references it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
%\usepackage{hyperref} %Want to turn this on!!!!!
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\externaldocument[main:]{main1} %If you comment this off, can turn on the hyperref

\begin{document}
    \section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}
       \begin{equation}
       B = C\label{eq:bc}
       \end{equation} 
     local ref: \cref{sec:mysection}, external ref: \cref{main:sec:mytitle}\\
     local eq ref: \cref{eq:bc}, external ref: \cref{main:eq:ab}\\
\end{document}
```

If you compile this above, it will work and generate the correct references to the local and external files.  However, if you turn on the `hyperref`, it doesn't compile.  Conversely.  If you comment out the `\externaldocument` and turn on the `hyperref`, it works fine (though it doesn't find the remove references, of course).

**Question:**
I want to use all of these together so that I can get hyperrefs in my PDF, use `\cref` for the references, and load in external documents.  How can I get this to work? Or am I missing something obvious?

I don't need for hyperlinks between the documents themselves, so if that is the source of the problem and something I can turn off, then that is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of these packages are changes the way references are written in the `.aux` file.  The correct load order is

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

but you need this in both the main and the external document.  So

external document `main1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}     

\begin{document}

\section{MyTitle}\label{sec:mytitle}            

\begin{equation}
  A = b\label{eq:ab}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and main document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\externaldocument[main:]{main1}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}

\begin{equation}
  B = C\label{eq:bc}
\end{equation} 

Local ref: \cref{sec:mysection}, external ref: \cref{main:sec:mytitle}

Local eq ref: \cref{eq:bc}, external ref: \cref{main:eq:ab}

\end{document}
```

will work providing hyperrefs everywhere.